# Multiple rows insert with ContentProvider

Tags: android, insert, android-contentprovider

I need to make insert of few rows in one transaction. Can I do it with ContentProvider?

Comment: Question is Unclear.. anyhow you can look here http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-providers.html#modifying

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5596354/insertion-of-thousands-of-contact-entries-using-applybatch-is-slow

Answer (score 18, accepted):

On the client side, `ContentResolver` supports a `bulkInsert()` method. Those will not necessarily be processed in a single transaction by the `ContentProvider`, simply because there may not be any transactions performed by the `ContentProvider`.

Comment: As I understand, if it is not overrriden - it will just call few standrt 'insert' methods?

Comment: Correct. You have no idea if any given `ContentProvider` overrides `bulkInsert()`, unless it is your own `ContentProvider`.

Comment: I think you should go with ContentProviderOperations, read this tutorial http://www.grokkingandroid.com/better-performance-with-contentprovideroperation/

Answer (score 22):

I have implemented this in my app and here's the gist of the code that I use.

In my content provider, I have overridden the applyBatch() method and it's a very simple method to override:

```
/**
 * Performs the work provided in a single transaction
 */
@Override
public ContentProviderResult[] applyBatch(
        ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation> operations) {
    ContentProviderResult[] result = new ContentProviderResult[operations
            .size()];
    int i = 0;
    // Opens the database object in "write" mode.
    SQLiteDatabase db = mOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    // Begin a transaction
    db.beginTransaction();
    try {
        for (ContentProviderOperation operation : operations) {
            // Chain the result for back references
            result[i++] = operation.apply(this, result, i);
        }

        db.setTransactionSuccessful();
    } catch (OperationApplicationException e) {
        Log.d(TAG, "batch failed: " + e.getLocalizedMessage());
    } finally {
        db.endTransaction();
    }

    return result;
}
```

The result is given to the next operation because you want to support back references. When I actually want to change stuff in the database in this single transaction I loop over my content and do stuff like this:

```
operations.add(ContentProviderOperation
                    .newInsert(
                            Uri.withAppendedPath(
                                    NotePad.Notes.CONTENT_ID_URI_BASE,
                                    Long.toString(task.dbId)))
                    .withValues(task.toNotesContentValues(0, listDbId))
                    .build());
// Now the other table, use back reference to the id the note
// received
noteIdIndex = operations.size() - 1;

operations.add(ContentProviderOperation
                    .newInsert(NotePad.GTasks.CONTENT_URI)
                    .withValues(task.toGTasksContentValues(accountName))
                    .withValueBackReferences(
                            task.toGTasksBackRefContentValues(noteIdIndex))
                    .build());
```

You just need to remember to finish by calling:

```
provider.applyBatch(operations);
```

This will perform your stuff in a single transaction and supports backreferences if you need the id from an earlier insert without issue.

Answer (score 7):

Here an **example for bulkInsert**:

```
/**
 * Perform bulkInsert with use of transaction
 */
@Override
public int bulkInsert(Uri uri, ContentValues[] values) {
    int uriType = 0;
    int insertCount = 0;
    try {

        uriType = sURIMatcher.match(uri);
        SQLiteDatabase sqlDB = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();

        switch (uriType) {
        case MEASUREMENTS:
            try {
                sqlDB.beginTransaction();
                for (ContentValues value : values) {
                    long id = sqlDB.insert(Tab_Measurements.TABLE_NAME, null, value);
                    if (id > 0)
                        insertCount++;
                }
                sqlDB.setTransactionSuccessful();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // Your error handling
            } finally {
                sqlDB.endTransaction();
            }
            break;
        default:
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unknown URI: " + uri);
        }
        // getContext().getContentResolver().notifyChange(uri, null);
    } catch (Exception e) {
      // Your error handling
    }

    return insertCount;
}
```

And in your code something like:

```
/**
 * Inserts new measurement information.
 * 
 * @param ArrayList of measurements
 * @return number of inserted entries
 */
public static long bulkInsertEntries(ArrayList<Item_Measurement> readings) {
    // insert only if data is set correctly
    if (readings.size() == 0)
        return 0;

    long insertCount = 0;
    try {
        // insert new entries

        // ArrayList<ContentValues> valueList = new ArrayList<ContentValues>();
        ContentValues[] valueList = new ContentValues[readings.size()];
        int i = 0;
        for (Item_Measurement reading : readings) {
            ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
            values.put(COL_TIME_READING, reading.getTimeReading());
                            // ...
            valueList[i++] = values;
        }

        // returns ID
        insertCount = ContentProviderOwn.getAppContext().getContentResolver()
                .bulkInsert(ContentProviderOwn.MEASUREMENTS_URI_BASE, valueList);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        // Your error handling
    }
    return insertCount;
}
```

Comment: How is this better than calling a regular insert in a loop from the original array of data? Are there performance benefits in using BulkInsert?

Comment: @AndrewS bulkInsert() is much better on big operations. Just finished optimization in my app: applyBatch() with 2000 operations on several tables takes 2000 ms, 10 bulkInsert's takes 100 ms.

Comment: I notice you have the `notifyChange` commented out. What is the benefit of doing that or not?

Answer (score 3):

I also use replace mode for insert row - 
db.insertWithOnConflict(EVENT_TABLE_NAME, null, value, SQLiteDatabase.CONFLICT_REPLACE);
Its will rid of conflict if record is exist already

In DatabaseHelper add UNIQUE INDEX

```
    public class DataProvider extends ContentProvider {

    private static class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
        DatabaseHelper(Context context){
            super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db){
            db.execSQL(CREATE_EVENT_TABLE);
            db.execSQL("CREATE UNIQUE INDEX event_idx ON " + EVENT_TABLE_NAME + " ( " + EventTable.EVENT_ID + " )");
// ...

        ...
        @Override
        public int bulkInsert(Uri uri, ContentValues[] values) {
            Log.i(TAG, "bulkInsert");
            if (values.length == 0)
                return 0;
            int insertCount = 0;
            try {
                switch (uriMatcher.match(uri)) {
                    case EVENT_LIST:
                        try {
                            db.beginTransaction();
                            for (ContentValues value : values) {
                                long id = db.insertWithOnConflict(EVENT_TABLE_NAME, null, value, SQLiteDatabase.CONFLICT_REPLACE);
                                if (id > 0)
                                    insertCount++;
                            }
                            db.setTransactionSuccessful();
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            // Your error handling
                        } finally {
                            db.endTransaction();
                        }
                        break;
                    default:
                        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unknown URI " + uri);
                }
                getContext().getContentResolver().notifyChange(uri, null);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.i(TAG, "Exception : " + e);
            }
            return insertCount;
        }
```

And call bulkInsert like this:

```
            ContentValues[] cvArr = new ContentValues[eventList.size()];
            long insertCount = 0;
            int i = 0;
            for (Event event : eventList) {
                ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
                cv.put(DataProvider.EventTable.EVENT_ID, event.id);
                cv.put(DataProvider.EventTable.SENSOR_ID, event.sensor_id);
                cv.put(DataProvider.EventTable.TIMESTAMP, event.time);
                cvArr[i++] = cv;
            }
            // returns ID
            insertCount = context.getContentResolver()
                    .bulkInsert(DataProvider.CONTENT_EVENT_LIST, cvArr);
```