# Best practices for synchronizing a SQL database with a REST remote server on Android

Tags: android, sql, sqlite, synchronization, android-contentprovider

I have a custom Android `ContentProvider` which stores and retrieves data from a SQLite database.

Let's assume one of the DB tables has an `_ID` column and a `NAME` column and a content like this:

```
|==========|==========|
|   _ID    |   NAME   |
|==========|==========|
|    1     |    d1    |
|    2     |    d2    |
|    3     |    d3    |
|    4     |    d4    |
|==========|==========|
```

This SQLite DB is kept in sync with a remote database and new data is fetched periodically over the network.
The possible operations on the table are as follows:

1. Existing rows can be deleted
2. New rows can be added
3. The NAME column of existing rows can be modified

Let's now assume that all the possible operations happen at once and, after fetching some up-to-date data from a remote server, the new content of this table has to be set as follows:

```
|==========|==========|
|   _ID    |   NAME   |
|==========|==========|
|    1     |    d7    |
|    3     |    d3    |
|    4     |    d6    |
|    5     |    d5    |
|==========|==========|
```

There can be two different approaches to do that:

1. Query the database and check each existing rows to see if they need to be updated, then add any new rows and delete any missing rows - though this method can be a bit tricky in case we want to update the database with a pagination approach and not with a single network fetch
2. Delete the entire table with a single `DELETE` SQL command and then add all the rows received from the server

On Android, I am currently implementing the second method with *batch operations* to maximize the performance:

```java
final ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation> operations = new ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation>();

// with this URI, the content provider deletes all rows
operations.add(ContentProviderOperation.newDelete(Users.CONTENT_URI).build());

final ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
values.put(ID_COLUMN, 1);
values.put(NAME_COLUMN, "d7");
values.put(ID_COLUMN, 3);
values.put(NAME_COLUMN, "d3");
values.put(ID_COLUMN, 4);
values.put(NAME_COLUMN, "d6");
values.put(ID_COLUMN, 5);
values.put(NAME_COLUMN, "d5");

operations.add(ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(Users.CONTENT_URI).withValues(values).build());

getApplicationContext().getContentResolver().applyBatch(MyContentProvider.AUTHORITY, operations);
```

Is this the best approach, or would method 1 (or some other method) be better in terms of performance?

EDIT: for example, taking approach 2, an overridden `ContentProvider#bulkInsert` which uses database transactions could speed up the batch-insert operation a lot: see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5596354/insertion-of-thousands-of-contact-entries-using-applybatch-is-slow).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best option requires proper API implementation - when you should store some db_version(int or timestamp of last update, or whatever).

And during update server responds with data, and operation type - add, update, delete.

Comment: I'm afraid this is not possible. The server REST API just returns the list of items in a JSON representation and it is client agnostic. No sync-specific information is available from the server.

Comment: Delete all and insert new items then.

Comment: Yes, I also think this is the only option in this case. I was just thinking that if I managed to convince the web service guys to add this sync API, this would add much more flexibility. The anchor might be the last modified date and a client could ask the server for all the items that have been added/modified/deleted after a specified date. However, for the deleted items, the server needs to keep track of the deleted items, but how? maybe not actually deleting any items but simply marking them as "deleted" in the database? Wouldn't the DB size grow more then needed in this case?