# Easiest way to enter more than one rows in a table

Tags: android, sqlite, android-intent

When the first time i am running the app, i want to create a table and enter some rows into the table. For doing this, i wrote this bit of code and it is working fine:

```
            //Creating the table
        db.execSQL(MRM_BOOKING_LOGIN_TABLE_CREATE);         
        //Setting the values in the table
        ContentValues contentValuesLogin = new ContentValues();
        contentValuesLogin.put(USER_ID, "asdf");
        contentValuesLogin.put(PASSWORD, "1234");
        //Inserting a row in the table
        db.insert(MRM_BOOKING_LOGIN_TABLE, null, contentValuesLogin);
```

But i want to enter at least 15 to 20 rows in the table. Is it a good idea that every time after inserting one row, i will clear the ContentValues object (or create another object of ContentValues) and enter another row in the newly created table? In this way, the lines of code will increase a lot as well. I am sure there might be some other better alternative way to do the same. Please suggest

Regards,

Comment: Am I to assume that your 15-20 rows have hard-coded values (the user id and password is known ahead of time) or are they generated by some other means? If they are hard-coded, you can use resource string arrays and loops over them.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can insert multiple rows using  `ContentResolver.bulkInsert (Uri url, ContentValues[] values)`.

More information can be had from here:

[Insertion of thousands of contact entries using applyBatch is slow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5596354/insertion-of-thousands-of-contact-entries-using-applybatch-is-slow)

Hope this will help you.

Comment: i guess it might be valid for **ContentResolver** but not **SQLite** directly

Answer (score 2):

I think, the only way to insert multiple records via `db.insert` is to use a *loop*. Combine it together with SQLite **Transaction** and it will speed up the process.

Comment: then use **DatabaseUtils.InsertHelper**. read this http://www.outofwhatbox.com/blog/2010/12/android-using-databaseutils-inserthelper-for-faster-insertions-into-sqlite-database/

Answer (score 2):

A sample code:

```
try {
            // open the database
            db.beginTransaction();

            for (your objects) {
                ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
                cv.put(COL1, obj.p1);
                cv.put(COL2, obj.p2);
                //.....

                long id = db.insertOrThrow(DATABASE_TABLE, COL_Id, cv);
            }

            db.setTransactionSuccessful();
} catch (Exception e) {
            throw e;
        } finally {
            db.endTransaction();
            // close database
        }
```