# Bulk update of more than 500 contacts

Tags: android

I am developing an app that needs to update many contacts and I am getting the following error.

> android.content.OperationApplicationException: Too many content provider operations between yield points. The maximum number of operations per yield point is 500

I tried breaking the contacts up into smaller chunks to update, but I still get the same error. The good thing is that now, some contacts are updated (previously 0 contacts are updated). Any suggestions that can help me is greatly appreciated.

```
    Uri uri = ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI;
    String selectionUpdate = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone._ID + " = ? AND " + ContactsContract.Contacts.Data.MIMETYPE + " = ? ";

    int i = 0;
    int numRowsUpdated = 0;
    int batchsize = 100;
    for (EntityPhone ep : eps) { 
        if (ep.isUpdateNumber()) {

            //update only when checkbox is ticked
            ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newUpdate(uri)
                    .withSelection(selectionUpdate, new String[]{ep.getPhoneId(), ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE})
                    .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER, ep.getPhoneNumberNew())
                    .build());

            i++;
            if (i % batchsize == 0) {

                i = 0;
                ContentProviderResult[] count = contentResolver.applyBatch(ContactsContract.AUTHORITY, ops);

                if (count != null) {
                    numRowsUpdated += count.length;
                    Log.i(TAG, "batch update success" + count.length);
                } else {

                    Log.w(TAG, "batch update failed");
                }
            }
        }
    }

    if (i != 0) {
        ContentProviderResult[] count = contentResolver.applyBatch(ContactsContract.AUTHORITY, ops);
    }
```

I have looked at the past questions, but they are mostly related to inserts, not updates.

- [Insertion of thousands of contact entries using applyBatch is slow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5596354/insertion-of-thousands-of-contact-entries-using-applybatch-is-slow)
- [Whats the fastest way to create large numbers of contacts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10736441/whats-the-fastest-way-to-create-large-numbers-of-contacts)

The reason why I want to update so many records at once is because my application is a 'contact number formatter' that allows the user to standardizes all the phone numbers in the phone easily. I do not have control of how many records the users want to update in a single batch. (https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=angel.phoneformat)

Comment: Shouldn't you be clearing ops inside the if(i % batchsize ==0)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're not creating a new object for `ops`.  During subsequent calls to `applyBatch`, you're passing the previously applied operations back in as well.  The first time `ops` contains 100 elements, then 200 and eventually it fails when it reaches 500.  Change to

```
if (i % batchsize == 0) {
    contentResolver.applyBatch(ContactsContract.AUTHORITY, ops);
    ops = new ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation>(100);
}
```

Comment: Thank you, let me try it out.