# How to quickly insert thousands of contacts

Tags: android

I am a rookie.I am developing a project that requires me to insert quickly thousands of contacts into android and then to delete them. I have read carefully the page on [Insertion of thousands of contact entries using applyBatch is slow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5596354/insertion-of-thousands-of-contact-entries-using-applybatch-is-slow). I want to use the method that was mentioned on '4 Answers',but I can't understand some variables and class, such as mOpenHelper, Tables.GUYS and Guys.STRINGCOLUMNTYPE. I need your help.

I have known how to insert data into SQLite, but I find that there are lots of tables in contacts2.db located on /data/data/com.android.providers.contacts/databases. However, I only need to insert two field,name and phone number, into contacts2.db. I cann't analyze those tables because they are too many.