# Most Efficient Way to Insert 5000+ Android Contacts

Tags: android, contacts

I realize this has been somewhat touched upon in various places including [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5596354/insertion-of-thousands-of-contact-entries-using-applybatch-is-slow) on Stack Overflow, but I'm looking for any other solutions that people might have used.  So with that in mind...

I'm developing an application where a user can initially sync all his contacts with a desktop application OTA.  This is done through a web service call that grabs a set of 100 contacts from the server, downloads and parses the information, inserts the contacts into the Android Contact DB, acknowledges receipt of these contacts, and then repeats the previous steps with the next set of 100 contacts until the sync is complete.  This process works well when a user has contacts on the order or 1000-2000, but a typical user of this application can easily have 5000-6000 contacts (with power users having upwards of 10000+) in which case things take far longer than I'd like.  For example, a sample set of approximately 5300 contacts can take about 13.5 minutes to complete.  Not bad, but I'd like it to be at least as efficient as iOS which runs about 8 minutes for the same data set if possible.

I've logged the time it takes for each step and, unsurprisingly, the bottleneck appears to be with inserting the data into the Android contract DB.  After scouring the web I've found little help with regards to inserting thousands of contacts, but what I have found seems to fall into these three groups:

1) ContentProviderOperation -- The Google recommended way which gave me my baseline of 13.5 minutes for 5300 contacts.

2) Bulk Inserts -- I read that builkInsert tends to be more efficient than applyBatch, but when I tried to implement this myself it actually took 25 minutes for the same 5300 contacts.  I have a feeling a lot of this is due to the fact that I need to insert the RawContact information and then save the resulting URI for use in creating the ContactsContract.Data for the bulkInsert which comes more naturally via the backValueReference in the ContentProviderOperation.  Additionally, I looked at the android source code and I don't get the feeling that bulkInsert is terribly efficient.

3) Creating an optimized bulk insert using the DatabaseUtils.InsertHelper and transactions -- Unfortunately, this seems geared towards those people who created their own content provider because you need access to the underlying DB as an instance variable and I've yet to see how that could be done with the native contacts DB.

Does anyone have any experience with inserting 5000+ contacts or any other possible ideas I could look into to help reduce my time?  Or should the ContentProviderOperation be considered as optimized as it's going to get?

Comment: If your only metric is "as good as iOS" you may find this, and other tasks, impossible. Each platform will have different advantages due to differing optimizations.

Comment: 1) vs 2) depends a lot on implementation details. Both just bundle a bunch of operations and the default implementation would just do single operations instead of transactions. Stay with what works best for you, you can't optimitze the provider internal implementation

Comment: That's probably a fair response.  Maybe the metric should have just been faster than the current 13.5 minutes.  I fully understand there is a little bit of an apples to oranges comparison, but with that said 13 minutes seems awfully slow.  Especially in light of the fact that it's not uncommon for a user to have 10000+ contacts.

Comment: Providing some code may help, as someone may notice that you are doing something in slow way. Also, have you tried running downloads and inserts on different Threads to see if that makes any significant difference? Out of curiosity how large is 5000+ contacts memory wise? More info may help others help you :)

Comment: In regard to the bulkInsert, how do you save the resulting raw contact URI? I'm having issues in connecting the raw contact table and data table doing 2 bulk inserts.

Comment: 10 years later, is there a better way to do things now?

Comment: @ChagaiFriedlander I didn't find a better way to do it, although there was only a limited support for Android so we never revisited things. I think the biggest helper was updated hardware and networking speeds.

Comment: ok thx! I'm getting crashed as well...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, I believe 1 is the best option. I suspect a majority of your overhead in comparison to iPhone is in the cross process IPC inherent to the content provider design.

Your analysis of 3 is correct.

There are options on rooted devices to go around the content provider but I doubt that is what you are looking for.

Answer (score -1):

Hi I insert huge contact within minutes my code is:

```
public void insertContact(contactList:List<Contact>){

  val queueSize = 300 //400
            val contactQueue = contactList.size/queueSize

            if(contactQueue > 0) {

                var startIndex = 0
                var endIndex = 0

                var tempList: List<Request.ContactBean>? = null

                totalQueue = contactQueue + 1+smsQueue

                for (i in 0..contactQueue) {

                    startIndex = i * queueSize
                    endIndex = startIndex + queueSize

                    endIndex = if (endIndex < contactList.size) endIndex else contactList.size

                    tempList = contactList.subList(startIndex, endIndex);

                    Log.d(Constant.TAG_RESTORE, "In loop totalQueue: " + contactQueue + " i: " + i
                            + " startIndex: " + startIndex + "endIndex: " + endIndex + " Queuesize: " + tempList.size)

                    restoreContact(tempList);
                }
            }else{
                totalQueue = 1+smsQueue;
                restoreContact(contactList);

            }
}





    private fun restoreContact( contactList: List<Request.ContactBean>) {



        Observable.fromCallable { insertContact(contactList); }
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe({
                    totalCompleteOperation++

                    if(totalCompleteOperation === totalQueue){

                        Log.d(Constant.TAG_RESTORE, " in subscribe restoreContact " +
                                "totalCompleteOperation: "+ totalCompleteOperation +" totalQueue "+totalQueue)

                        hideDialog();
                        completeRestore(true)
                    }
                }

                )
    }



    public void insertContact(List<Request.ContactBean> contacts) throws RemoteException, OperationApplicationException {

        final int MAX_OPERATIONS_FOR_INSERTION = 100; //100
        int size = contacts.size();

            ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation> ops = new ArrayList<>();
            for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {

                createOperations(ops, contacts.get(i));
                if (ops.size() >= MAX_OPERATIONS_FOR_INSERTION) {
                    mContext.getContentResolver().applyBatch(ContactsContract.AUTHORITY, ops);
                    ops.clear();
                }
            }
            if (ops.size() > 0)
                mContext.getContentResolver().applyBatch(ContactsContract.AUTHORITY, ops); 

    }


    private void createOperations(ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation> ops,
                                                  Request.ContactBean contact){
        int backReference = ops.size();
        ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(ContactsContract.RawContacts.CONTENT_URI)
                .withValue(ContactsContract.RawContacts.ACCOUNT_NAME, null)
                .withValue(ContactsContract.RawContacts.ACCOUNT_TYPE, null)
                .withValue(ContactsContract.RawContacts.AGGREGATION_MODE, ContactsContract.RawContacts.AGGREGATION_MODE_DISABLED)
                .build()
        );
            ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI)
                   // .withYieldAllowed(true)
                    .withValueBackReference(ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, backReference)
                    .withValue(ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
                    .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.GIVEN_NAME, contact.getName())
                    .build());

            if (contact.getNumbers() != null && contact.getNumbers().size() > 0) {
                // Adding insert operation to operations list
                // to insert Mobile Number in the table ContactsContract.Data
                ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI)
                        //.withYieldAllowed(true)
                        .withValueBackReference(ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, backReference)
                        .withValue(ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE, Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
                        .withValue(Phone.NUMBER, contact.getNumbers().get(0).getNumber())
                        .withValue(Phone.TYPE, Phone.TYPE_MOBILE)
                        .build());
                if (contact.getNumbers().size() > 1) {
                    // Adding insert operation to operations list
                    // to  insert Home Phone Number in the table ContactsContract.Data
                    ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI)
                            //.withYieldAllowed(true)
                            .withValueBackReference(ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, backReference)
                            .withValue(ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE, Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
                            .withValue(Phone.NUMBER, contact.getNumbers().get(1).getNumber())
                            .withValue(Phone.TYPE, Phone.TYPE_HOME)
                            .build());
                }

            }
            if (contact.getEmails() != null && contact.getEmails().size() > 0) {
                // Adding insert operation to operations list
                // to insert Work Email in the table ContactsContract.Data
                ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI)
                       // .withYieldAllowed(true)
                        .withValueBackReference(ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, backReference)
                        .withValue(ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE, Email.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
                        .withValue(Email.ADDRESS, contact.getEmails().get(0).getAddress())
                        .withValue(Email.TYPE, Email.TYPE_WORK)
                        .build());
            }
            if (contact.getEmails().size() > 1) {
                // Adding insert operation to operations list
                // to insert Home Email in the table ContactsContract.Data
                ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI)
                       // .withYieldAllowed(true)
                        .withValueBackReference(ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, backReference)
                        .withValue(ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE, Email.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
                        .withValue(Email.ADDRESS, contact.getEmails().get(1).getAddress())
                        .withValue(Email.TYPE, Email.TYPE_HOME)
                        .build());
            }

    }

This code will insert huge contact list in very less time.
```